# Cannot connect to sqlserver from java application

Tags: java, sql-server, netbeans

i have web service which needs to connect to a sqlserver to do the login, but somehow it does not work and it throws an exception. I used the following steps to connect:

From service client:

```
 TrackingWS_Service service=new TrackingWS_Service();
 User user = service.getTrackingWSPort().login(username,password);
```

TrackingWS_Service which is a generated class from the same project:

```
@WebServiceClient(name = "TrackingWS", targetNamespace = "http://webservices/", wsdlLocation =  "http://localhost:8080/TrackingSystem/TrackingWS?wsdl")
 public class TrackingWS_Service extends Service
 {
    @WebEndpoint(name = "TrackingWSPort")
    public TrackingWS getTrackingWSPort() {
    return super.getPort(new QName("http://webservices/", "TrackingWSPort"), TrackingWS.class);
    }
 }
```

the interface TrackingWs:

```
 @WebService(name = "TrackingWS", targetNamespace = "http://webservices/")
 @XmlSeeAlso({
 ObjectFactory.class
 })
 public interface TrackingWS {

    @WebMethod
    @WebResult(targetNamespace = "")
    @RequestWrapper(localName = "login", targetNamespace = "http://webservices/", className = "webservices.Login")
    @ResponseWrapper(localName = "loginResponse", targetNamespace = "http://webservices/", className = "webservices.LoginResponse")
    @Action(input = "http://webservices/TrackingWS/loginRequest", output = "http://webservices/TrackingWS/loginResponse")
     public User login(
    @WebParam(name = "arg0", targetNamespace = "")
    String arg0,
    @WebParam(name = "arg1", targetNamespace = "")
    String arg1);
 }
```

And in the service project i have the following:

TrackingWs - the web service:

```
 @WebService(serviceName = "TrackingWS")
 public class TrackingWS {
   @WebMethod
   public User login(String username,String password){
   DBOperations dbOperations=new DBOperations();
   return dbOperations.findUser(username, password);     
   }
 }
```

DBOperations:

```
public class DBOperations {
private Connection connection = null;
private ResultSet rs = null;
private java.sql.PreparedStatement pst = null;

public synchronized User findUser(String username,String password){
connection=Connect.ConnectDb();

String sql="SELECT * FROM [Assignment5].[dbo].[User] WHERE Username=? AND Password=?";
        User user=null;
        int id;
        String usrname;
        String pasword;
        String type;
    try{
        pst=connection.prepareStatement(sql);
        pst.setString(1, username);
        pst.setString(2, password);
        rs=pst.executeQuery();
        if(rs.next()){
                    id=rs.getInt("ID");
                    usrname=rs.getString("Username");
                    pasword=rs.getString("Password");
                type=rs.getString("Type");    
                user=new User(id,usrname,pasword,type);
                    close();
                    return user;
            }

    }
    catch(SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
    try {
        close();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(DBOperations.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
  return user;
}
```

}

and finally the connection:

public class Connect {
   // Connection conn=null;

```
public static Connection ConnectDb(){

    try {
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=Assignment5;integratedSecurity=true;");  
    return conn;
}
catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
                    return null;
}
}
```

}

I set the sqljdbc4 and i also copied the sqljdbc_auth.dll in the web service project. I have no idea why it throws the exception when calling getConnection().

Comment: 1. You didnt loaded driver class. 2. What's the error? No suitable driver found or class not found?

Comment: What error or exception are you getting...please print the stack trace

Comment: i can't really see the error because i try to connect to db from the service and i get the error on the catch branch when i want to display the error, so i only know that it happens when i try to connect to db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i made it work, i just had to to add the jdbc jar to glassfish-4.1\glassfish\domains\domain1\lib folder

Answer (score 1):

Possible reason for getting the Exception while connecting SQLServer with java

1. When the class path is not properly set.
2. Add the resource of the database in the context.xml file of the server you are using
   like this

> ```
> <Resource name="jdbc/vt"
>
> auth="Container"
>
> type="javax.sql.DataSource"
>
> username="ankit"
>
> password="ankit"
>
> driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
>
> url="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=vt"
>
> maxActive="15"
>
> maxIdle="3"/>
> ```

3. After adding the resource set the reference to that resource in your application web.xml file like this

> ```
> <resource-ref>
>     <description>Connection Pool</description>
>     <res-ref-name>jdbc/vt</res-ref-name>
>     <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
>     <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
> </resource-ref>
> ```

Note: the resource are according to my project, change it accordingly to yours.

Hope it helps

Comment: i am using glassfish, i could't find the context file

Comment: look out for conf folder in the root directory of glassfish there you will find all the xml file to configue glassfish.


M not sure about glassfish but check if there any application.xml file


actually for tomcat context.xml is the file whose content are loaded for each web application on startup